# Word for "Get the last values" in the context of coding

Tags: sentence, sentence-starts

I'm translating the documentation for a program, and I want to write that a certain function gets the last values you've entered. I'm stuck on the word "**Query**" (as in "Query of the number of found 3D points of the last call of DisplayPosScan") but I don't like this sentence at all. There are too many "of" somehow, and it just doesn't look good. I think it's because of the word **query**, but I've looked at this single sentence for so long that it doesn't make any sense anymore.

So to clear things up a little bit, the function I'm writing about (`NumberOfFoundPoints`) gets the amount of 3D points of the last time the function `DisplayPosScan` has been called, then it returns this value as a String.

Comment: What's wrong with how you expressed it in the last paragraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think *returns* is the word you want:

> `NumberOfFoundPoints` returns the number of 3D points as of the last time the function `DisplayPosScan` was called.

Comment: Thank you so much @Barmar, I guess I didn't see the forest for the trees here :D

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

> *NumberOfFoundPoints* receives (takes) as input the number of 3D points returned by *DisplayPosScan* the last time the latter was called. *NumberOfFoundPoints* then returns this value as a string.

@Barmar is mistaken in that *NumberOfFoundPoints* does not return the number of 3D points as of the last time *DisplayPosScan* was called. Instead, *NumberOfFoundPoints* takes that value as an input and returns it as a string.